# Why do I get IOException while creating images using lwuit?

Tags: android, java-me, lwuit

I am getting IOException when I try to create image in lwuit. 
the following is the code :
InputStream is = img.getResourceAsStream();
Image img = Image.createImage(is);

the actual size of images are 1 mb and above. Where I am able to create images of 100 or 200 kb in size with the same code.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the images 1 MB, **as compressed files?** A 1 MB compressed image will be quite a lot bigger uncompressed, which is what the mobile device needs to actually be displayed.

Comment: No! You may say that images are captured and directly sent to the j2me device where application opens that image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the size of your images is the reason

try to resize your images using this site 
http://www.picresize.com/

Comment: Yes! thanks! but could you please tell me if I can do it through coding in midlet. I have tried resizing images that i receive but it needs an image to be created first of all and then manipulate its rgb data. Where I am getting IOException while creating image at first. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Here I am using Lwuit createImage(Path) method and passing image path as an argument.

Comment: Please write your full code and give me an example of image you want to create   by link   or upload it  .                     That  makes me faster and better help you .